# Facebook Like Box - stream height

Tags: facebook, height, facebook-likebox

I'm experiencing a problem when changing the data-height from the Like Box plugin, when data-show-faces is set to "true". Changing the data-height to a larger value will only create (an) extra row(s) of faces, the data-stream will remain the same size.
What should I do to only show 2 rows of faces, but display a bigger data stream?

The code I'm using right now:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/*****" data-width="875" data-height="600" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

TIA.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known and reported Facebook bug. Their development team is working on a fix. You can track the progress here:

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/223956607795977/